# Laravel doesn't show errors on the screen but shows 404 Not Found page of Nginx

Tags: laravel

I set APP_DEBUG to true, in .env file. But Laravel doesn't show error messages and the details of error on the screen. Instead, Laravel shows 404 Not Found page of Nginx.

So, I have to check laravel.log with terminal app, every time an error happens.

I use Laravel 8. I installed it today, and this happens by default.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you are seeing the nginx 404 page that means that you have not set up your host configuration correctly in nginx.

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for the comment. after reading your comment, I reviewed nginx.conf and found the solution. I posted the answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display Laravel errors on the screen, remove all existing `error_page` directives of 404, 500, etc from nginx.conf and add `error_page 404 /index.php;`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment